# python imap email collector errorso

Tags: python

I have a script which is supposed to login via imap, and scan my mailbox for email addresses i have sent mail to. It seems there is an error in the code below. Would it be best to just scan named boxes or is there another fix?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# imap-email-address-collector
# 
import sys
import re
import csv
import getpass
import imaplib
import argparse
from email.parser import HeaderParser

RE_EMAIL = re.compile(r'^[a-z0-9._%+-]+\@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$')
RE_QUOTES = re.compile(r'[\'\"]')
RE_SPACES = re.compile(r'[\n\t\s]+')

NOSSL_PROMT = 'LETTHEWOLDREADALLMESSAGES'

results = {}
unmatched = set()


def matchAndAdd(email, name=''):
    email = email.lower()
    if RE_EMAIL.match(email):
        if email not in results or len(name) > len(results[email]): # only overwrite with longer name
            results[email] = name.strip()
    else:
        unmatched.add(email)


def grabAddress(address):
    address = str(address).strip()
    address = RE_QUOTES.sub('', address)
    address = RE_SPACES.sub(' ', address)

    if address.startswith('<'): # No name, just an email address
        address = address[1:]
        if address.endswith('>'):
            address = address[:-1]
        matchAndAdd(address)

    else: # Name and email address
        try:
            name, email = address.split('<')
        except Exception:
            matchAndAdd(address)
        else:
            matchAndAdd(email[:-1], name)


def listBoxes(imap):
    boxes = imap.list()
    if boxes[0] == 'OK' and len(boxes) > 1:
        for box in boxes[1]:
            box = re.split(r'\) \".\" ', box, maxsplit=1)
            if len(box) == 2:
                yield box[1]
    else:
        print 'No folders found.'
        sys.exit(0)


def main(args):
    if args.password:
        password = args.password
    else:
        password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')

    if args.nossl:
        print 'Connecting to %s:%s without SSL...' % (args.host, args.port)
        if not args.donotannoyme:
            confirmation = raw_input('Please type %s:' % NOSSL_PROMT)
            if not confirmation == NOSSL_PROMT:
                print 'Good choice ;) (Disable with --donotannoyme)'
                sys.exit(1)
        imap = imaplib.IMAP4(args.host, args.port)
    else:
        print 'Connecting to %s:%s over SSL...' % (args.host, args.port)
        imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(args.host, args.port)

    try:
        imap.login(args.user, password)

    except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
        print "Login failed."
        sys.exit(1)
    else:

        print 'Logged in as %s' % args.user

    print 'Collecting email addresses from all messages...'

    for box in listBoxes(imap):
        print 'Scanning %s' % box

        imap.select(box, readonly=True)
        typ, data = imap.search(None, 'Inbox')
        count = 0

        for num in data[0].split():
            typ, data = imap.fetch(num, '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (TO FROM)])')
            headers = headerParser.parsestr(data[0][1])

            for h in ('From', 'To'):
                if headers[h]:
                    for address in headers[h].split(','):
                        grabAddress(address)

            count += 1
            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.write('\rScanned %s messages' % count)

        if count > 0:
            print ''

        imap.close()

    imap.logout()

    if len(results) > 0:
        print 'Found %s addresses' % len(results)

        if not args.csv:
            toStdout = True
        else:
            try:
                outFile = open(args.csv, 'wb')
            except Exception:
                toStdout = True
                print 'Cannot write to %s, dumping out here.' % args.csv
            else:
                toStdout = False

        if toStdout:
            outFile = sys.stdout
            print '======================================================='
        else:
            print 'Writing to %s' % args.csv

        writer = csv.writer(outFile)

        writer.writerows(list(results.items()))

        if toStdout:
            print '======================================================='
        else:
            outFile.close()

        if len(unmatched) > 0:
            print 'Could not interpret %s address(es): %s' % (len(unmatched), "'"+("', '".join(unmatched))+"'")
    else:
        print 'No addresses found'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    headerParser = HeaderParser()
    argParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    argParser.add_argument('--host', help='imap host address', required=True)
    argParser.add_argument('--user', help='login username', required=True)
    argParser.add_argument('--csv', help='(optional) output csv filepath')
    argParser.add_argument('--nossl', help='(optional) do not use ssl', action='store_true')
    argParser.add_argument('--donotannoyme', help='(optional) do not complain about non-ssl connections', action='store_true')
    argParser.add_argument('--password', help='(optional) login password (will be prompted otherwise)')
    argParser.add_argument('--port', help='(optional) imap host port, defaults to 993', type=int, default=993)

    main(argParser.parse_args())
```

However, when i execute the script i get the error below. What may be the solution to this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./imap.py", line 169, in <module>
    main(argParser.parse_args())
  File "./imap.py", line 99, in main
    typ, data = imap.search(None, 'Inbox')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 640, in search
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, *criteria)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1083, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 918, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.error: SEARCH command error: BAD ['Error in IMAP command SEARCH: Unknown argument INBOX (0.001 + 0.000 secs).']
```

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with imap.search(None, 'Inbox')? You're already iterating over all boxes and selecting them (incl. Inbox), so what exactly are you looking to do with the search?

Comment: prevent searching of gmail and to make the script execute without error